# Deploy ASP.NET MVC with MySql db on IIS production server (without VS on prod server)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I need to deploy ASP.NET MVC project with MySql database (NHibernate) on IIS production server. There is no Visual Studio on production server. I have VS only on my develop computer. Connecting to production server is available by RDP. How to deploy it with db?

Comment: You can use "Publish" feature provided by local VS in development machine, then configure connection string in web.config at production server. This will create DLL file to run in IIS even without VS installed.

Comment: Publisher don't see my db.

Comment: Try using `File System` as publish method besides `Web Deploy/FTP`, it doesn't require DB publishing. However, this way requires editing web.config file manually or using IIS Manager to use production server's connection string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Production server should have latest .Net framework. VS is not
   required in production server.
2. And then install MySQL and configure your database.
3. Publish the asp.net application into production server IIS.

Comment: I had configurated database and it is working. Could you explain me step by step how to publish my project?